# Can unix sockets be accessed without using __sock_recvmsg?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, kernel, unix-socket

I'm trying to debug an interaction between a driver and a user program that talks to each other using a unix socket.  So my question is: "Is the method `__sock_recvmsg` (in net/socket.c) the only way data is received from a socket or are there other methods in the kernel that read data from the socket?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found is kinda... If the socket is a normal unix socket then the output must go through __sock_recvmsg but it is possible to change the function that is called by the socket when receiving a message but then it's not  a normal unix socket.